# i don't want seeing the back side of an object in a transparent state in Shader Graph

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9sXc.png)

The problem is that you can see behind the scenes in transparent state.

my project

[view forward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTsnT.png)

[view right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j59G.png)

As you can see, all bones are already using transparent objects.

this is shader graph

[shadergraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tAyx.png)

i using hdrp unity 2021.2.7f

Comment: Which render pipeline are you using?

Comment: @shingo hdrp using

Comment: Try to enable "Depth Write" in Graphic Settings.

Comment: @shingo where is detph Write? It's not in the graphics settings.
I looked at the global hdrp one by one, but I'm not sure. Maybe there is a hidden menu like this...

Comment: It's in the shader graph editor, a panel is named [Graph Inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@14.0/manual/Graph-Settings-Menu.html).

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with the mesh Normals.

Try to apply same material in other 3D Game object.

Comment: i already apply same material in other object

Comment: How was the result, Same?

Comment: Yes it is same .Can you elaborate on why there is a problem with the normals?I don't know if I got it wrong, but I can't find it even when I search for it.

Comment: The most common problem with Normals is facing faces in the wrong direction.
This makes the object see throw. You can easily check that by enabling rendering both faces. And also can check that on Blender. But it looks like that's not your case.